# How to read text from url on jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, url

Hi i am trying to read    text from a url  when i try to  reap   url text it   print some   some other text in place of original text original text is in hindi  How ca i get  my  output

Here is my code

```
   <section>
    <div class="push">

     <table  width="100%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bordercolor='66A8FF'>
     <%

       URL url;
        try {
            // get URL content

            String a="http://122.160.81.37:8080/mandic/commoditywise?c=paddy";
            url = new URL(a);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(inputLine);

                   String s=inputLine.replace("|", "\n");

                    s=s.replace("~"," ");

                    StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
                    while(str.hasMoreTokens())
           {
       String mandi = str.nextElement().toString();

          String price = str.nextElement().toString();


    %>
     <tr bgcolor="0F57FF" style="border-collapse:collapse">
        <td width="50%" height="50px" align="center" style="font-size:24px;"><font color="#fff"><%= mandi%></font></td>
    <td  width="50%"  height="50px" align="center" style="font-size:24px"><font color="#fff"><%= price%></font></td>
  </tr>
    <%
}
            }
            br.close();

            //System.out.println(sb);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    

       %>

     </table>
    </div>
        </section>
```

i am getting this in output

```
à¤…à¤šà¥à¤›à¤¨à¥‡à¤°à¤¾  NIL
à¤†à¤—à¤°à¤¾  NIL
à¤«à¤¼à¤¤à¥‡à¤¹à¤¾à¤¬à¤¾à¤ NIL
```

Here is my simple code  which is giving right output

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class URLConetent{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URL url;

        try {
            // get URL content

            String a="http://122.160.81.37:8080/mandic/commoditywise?c=paddy";
            url = new URL(a);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            // open the stream and put it into BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                               new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                  //  sb.append(inputLine);
                   String s=inputLine.replace("|", "\n");

                    s=s.replace("~"," ");
                    //System.out.println(s);
                    StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
                    while(str.hasMoreTokens())
     // for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
  // if(str.hasMoreElements())
   {
       String mandi = str.nextElement().toString();

          String price = str.nextElement().toString();
          System.out.println("MANDI"+mandi);
          System.out.println("Price"+price);
    }
            }
            br.close();

            //System.out.println(sb);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: can you show what is getting printed.

Comment: dear i have updated in my post whatever i  am getting in output

Comment: when I open the URL on my browser I see junk characters. can you confirm that you don't have any plugin for the same?

Comment: i dont have any plugin when i run same code on   console it print actual value

Comment: when i tried on console i see this NIL
à¤†à¤—à¤°à¤¾
NIL
à¤«à¤¼à¤¤à¥‡à¤¹à¤¾à¤¬à¤¾à¤¦
NIL
à¤œà¤¾à¤—à¤¨à¥‡à¤°
hmm.. interesting.

Comment: i updated my code by using that code i am getting hindi font

Comment: You need to specify what encoding this is. It definitely isn't UTF-8. I'm assuming things "work" because your local encoding just happens to handle it. But if that's the case, I don't really know what the problem is.